# TFS merge between parent and child still behaving like baseless merge

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, version-control, merge, source-control-explorer

I have a rather large TFS setup, and recently created some new branches. Let's call the existing branch Parent and the new branch Child. Child was created directly from Parent via the "Branch" command in the VS2015 Source Control Explorer.

Now, some time later, when it came time to merge from Child to Parent, TFS decided that all of the files (almost 3,000 of them) needed to be 'merged'. This resulted in a massive changeset, and the inability to look at the changeset to determine what actually changed.

I thought this behavior was not supposed to occur with Parent/Child branches. Any ideas?

Comment: When merging two branches all files by merging at the root folder level will mark all files in the target branch as "merged". You can see which files have been changed by looking for "Merge, Edit" and "Merge, Add" etc.

Comment: Thank you. 99.9% of them just say 'merge', and a few say 'merge, edit', but do I really have to scroll through 3,000 files to determine the 'merge, edit'? That does not seem useful.

Comment: Yeah. That's the unfortunate case. You can compare them to just show the real differences.

Comment: Did you move or rename either of the branches?

Comment: @JamesReed No, these were new branches that did not get renamed or moved. It is very bizarre.

Comment: Did your Parent branch have any other child branch?

Comment: The big question is how many merge conflicts there are. If you've not been making changes in the parent, then the merge back from the child should go smoothly. If you've been making changes in both branches, then you'll potentially have conflicts.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Yes, it had 2 other child branches.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA Did your other two child branches  also got this phenomenon when you merged back? If so there may be something wrong with your parent branch.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT the merge from one of the children resulted in the baseless behavior, with all files being part of the changeset. A subsequent merge from a different child behaved normally.A test merge from yet a 3rd child, just now, behaved normally as well.

Comment: After some test, can't reproduce your issue. Give a try with [tfs merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/tfvc/merge-command) instead of IDE. And use the `/candidate` which Prints a list of all changesets in the source that have not yet been merged into the destination. To see if it contain all the changesets just like the baseless behavior.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Thank you. I will do this when I get an opportunity. Thank you. At the moment, after the initial baseless merge behavior, it seems as if they are behaving normally.

Comment: @JimRoth This was not about conflicts. There were perhaps a dozen files change in Parent and Child. However, VSTS still decided to involve 3,000 files in the merge changeset, 99%+ of which were not modified.